# How to show the set of stable polynomials equals to the set of Lorentzian polynomials in degree 2

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, co.combinatorics, linear-algebra, cv.complex-variables

Give a homogenous polynomial $f\in \mathbb{R}[x_1,\dots,x_n]$ of degree $2$ in $n$ variables, we can consider $f$ as a quadratic form.
We call $L_n^2:=$ the set of quadratic forms with nonnegative coefficients that have at most one positive eigenvalue.

We define $S_n^2:=$ the set of degree $2$ homogeneous stable polynomials in $n$ variables with nonnegative coefficients. A polynomial $f$ is stable if $f$ is non-vanishing on $\mathcal{H}^n$ or identically zero, where $\mathcal{H}$ is the open upper half plane in $\mathbb{C}$.

In literature, $L_n^d$ are called Lorentzian polynomial and $S_n^d$ are called stable polynomials. This paper [https://web.math.princeton.edu/~huh/Lorentzian.pdf](https://web.math.princeton.edu/%7Ehuh/Lorentzian.pdf) discussed the properties of these two sets. My question comes from Definition 2.6 of the paper where authors claim $L_n^2=S_n^2$ and authors give an explicit description of $L_n^2$ as the closure of $\mathring{L}_n^2$ on page 2. I'm just wondering why these two sets are equal.

Thank you!